# can't make "sleep" command to run in executable script.sh using "io.elementary.terminal" command

Tags: pantheon-terminal, command-line, script

As  mentioned in the title, can't make sleep command to work in an executable script.sh with an io.elementary.terminal command is there something i'm missing?

```
#!/bin/sh
io.elementary.terminal -n -e "sleep 3s && ls"
```

returns:

```
sleep: invalid time interval ‘&&’
sleep: invalid time interval ‘ls’
Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Try `sleep 3s && io.elementary.terminal -n -e ls`

Comment: that did the trick! what a simple solution didn't think that I was obsessed in opening a new terminal window to make it work, it also works without the -n new window command:

```sleep 3s && io.elementary.terminal  -e ls```